# MVVMCross: Color Plugin produces compilation error but only in Release mode. In Debug mode it compiles OK

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I developed an MVVMCross/Xamarin.Android app and now I want to produce an APK for it. The instructions in Xamarin documentation say that debugging must be disabled and the app compiled in `Release mode`. But when I do this and compile I get the following compilation error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Color' does not exist in the namespace 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

in file `ColorPluginBootstrap.cs`

When I change back to `Debug Mode` the app compiles OK. Why is this? What I'm I missing here?

**Note:**
I'm using VS2012 and MVVMCross 3.0.14

TIA

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with mvvmcross. I have same issue only with bindings library for maps utility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & apologies for not coming back immediately after I solved it. The problem was solved by exiting & re-entering VS. The Color plugin libraries showed with an exclamation icon & even though they were there(I checked!) I removed them and re-added the references but from a different location(..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Color.3.0.14\lib\MonoAndroid) and...problem solved. Before that-when running in Debug Mode and before the switch to Release Mode-the two Dlls were from a different directory but I can't remember now which. Anyway, thanks again and apologies again.

Answer (score 0):

Your mvvmcross is pretty old.  Try the latest via nuget.  It has some fixes for linking issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jeremy but I don't do changes like that when I'm about to release the software, simply because it's too risky. For example, can you guarantee me that there are no breaking changes in 3.1.1 and that my app will run unchanged?